# How can I solve pandas error tokenizing data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .tsv file displayed below and I want to make dataframe of it using pandas. I am getting error tokenizing data. How can I overcome this error ?

Tsv file (data):

[image]

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("something/something.tsv", sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_csv` is by default taking your first line as a header.  `append` and `6.0` become your two headers.  Then it looks for two columns in subsequent rows.  In line 3 it finds 4 values and vomits.

You need another approach to handle this data where each line is a key-value pair with multiple values present.

**Per your comment - just read it all anyway**

Here's how you can do that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("something/something.tsv", sep='\t', header=None, names=np.arange(20))
```

`names=np.arange(20)` is the key - and can be whatever number is more than the number of values you will have in a row.  Then you can do whatever you need to do to get the data the way you want it.

Comment: I can do this with algoritmic way ofcourse but still I want to find if there is a simpler way of creating such dataframe...

Comment: @leskovecg Just updated my answer to just get the data read into a dataframe.